Stretching content tab container to 100%
How do I go about stretching my tab content container to 100% of the screen?



.season_tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 360px;
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.season_tab {
  float: left;  
  clear: both;
  width: 286px;
}

.season_tab label {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: -1px;
  font-size: 21px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
  width: 264px;
  height: 68px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.season_tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}

.season_content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 286px;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
 
.season_content span {
  animation: 0.5s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromTop; 
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-right-color: #FFF;
  border-left: 2px solid #2C71DA;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 2;
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .season_content {
  z-index: 1;
}
<div class="season_tabs">

   <div class="season_tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label for="tab-1">tab 1</label>

       <div class="season_content">
           <span>content 1</span>
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="season_tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">tab 2</label>

       <div class="season_content">
           <span>content 2</span>
       </div> 
   </div>

    <div class="season_tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">tab 3</label>

       <div class="season_content">
           <span>content 3</span>
       </div> 
   </div>
      <div class="season_tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-4" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-4">tab 4</label>

       <div class="season_content">
           <span>content 4</span>
       </div> 
   </div>

</div>




you could change the min-height of the .season_tabs to 100vh and remove the margin from this element and from the body.

Is this what you're hoping to accomplish? The major change is I added min-height: 100dvh; to your .session_tabs to make sure they're always full screen. dvh is the dynamic viewport height, taking up the full viewport minus the address bar on mobile.
You could also use absolute positioning to force a full view if needed, depending on your design needs.
Additionally, I removed margin from the body and .session_tabs to prevent it from having awkward gaps.
If anything needs clarification, don't hesitate to ask


body {
  margin: 0;
}

.season_tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 100dvh;
  clear: both;
}

.season_tab {
  float: left;  
  clear: both;
  width: 286px;
}

.season_tab label {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: -1px;
  font-size: 21px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
  width: 264px;
  height: 68px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.season_tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}

.season_content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 286px;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
 
.season_content span {
  animation: 0.5s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromTop; 
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-right-color: #FFF;
  border-left: 2px solid #2C71DA;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 2;
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .season_content {
  z-index: 1;
}
<div class="season_tabs">

   <div class="season_tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label for="tab-1">tab 1</label>

       <div class="season_content">
           <span>content 1</span>
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="season_tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">tab 2</label>

       <div class="season_content">
           <span>content 2</span>
       </div> 
   </div>

    <div class="season_tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">tab 3</label>

       <div class="season_content">
           <span>content 3</span>
       </div> 
   </div>
      <div class="season_tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-4" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-4">tab 4</label>

       <div class="season_content">
           <span>content 4</span>
       </div> 
   </div>

</div>




Very beautiful! works as expected. Is there a way to add a margin around the whole thing like 20px or so and still maintain the height without having to overflow the page?

You absolutely could add a 20px spacing without overflowing the page @JasonKelly. I would add another wrapper for .season_tabs that then has padding as my first choice of solution, if you just want spacing. If you want to force some margin, you could always use calc(100dvh - 2 * 20px) as your height and just add the 20px margin. I find this css less readable though. If you need a written example, let me know and I can edit my answer.
